# Работа CSS в разных браузерах

Tags: вёрстка, css

Я Java и C++ программист, WEB-разработку только осваиваю, посему просьба не кидать тапками.
Логично, что разные браузеры имеют разные движки, обрабатывают данные по разному. Но разве с простейшим CSS может возникать [подобное](http://www.cl.ly/0Q2j201n372p2E1d3W2J)? Слева Safari, справа Firefox 4.

[image]

При этом, стиль прописан в отдельном классе, указывается в теге `<span>`, сам класс:

```
color: red;
font-size: 200%;
position: relative;
font-family: serif;
top: 3px;
```

Как видно из скриншота, Firefox не "подхватил" шрифт serif, верно? Почему?-)

И вообще, расскажите о проверенных источниках в Сети, где можно почитать о всех мелких или не мелких особенностях кроссбраузерной вёрстки. Чем больше, тем лучше)

Спасибо.

**UPD** Я так понимаю такое происходит из-за установленного по-умолчанию шрифта в браузере?

Comment: CSS Reset не помог. В Firefox 4 не указан шрифт по-умолчанию + разрешено указание шрифта страницами.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru ---- поддерживаю сам всегда им пользуюсь

Answer (score 8):

[Serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) - это общее название набора шрифтов с засечками. Т.е. устанавливая font-family в значение serif, ты говоришь браузеру, что хочешь, что бы данный текст отображался шрифтом с засечками. А какой именно это будет шрифт, уже зависит от настроек браузера/системы.

Если необходимо, что бы во всех браузерах, по возможности, использовался один шрифт, то нужно указывать конкретный шрифт. Пример:

```
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
```

PS В Firefox настройка шрифтов для каждого из наборов находится в Menu -> Preferences -> Content -> Fonts & Colors -> Advanced

Answer (score 0):

http://htmlbook.ru - отличный справочник
Для каждого тега, атрибута, св-ва приводиться сравнительная таблица какими браузерами поддерживается, дается небольшое описание + пример